# How to achieve better caching control for ListView?

Tags: qt, qml

I tried to play with cacheBuffer, but it's only help me to increase count of cached delegates, when I want to disable caching at all.

Now with zero caching buffer my example (only one item stretched on all ListView) behaves like this:

- At the start ListView creates two delegates: currently visible and
  next one.
- When I scrolling list forward it creates and keep up to 4 delegates without beginning destroying them.
- When I start scrolling list backward it begin immediately destroying delegates without looking on cacheBuffer.
- If you replace "height: root.height" to "height: listView.height", it will create delegates for all model items at the start.

Is this behaviour normal? Can I change it some way?

You can tried it yourself:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

import Qt.labs.calendar 1.0

Window {
    id: root

    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
        id: listView

        anchors.fill: parent
        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
        cacheBuffer: 0

        model: 10

        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: root.height
            // height: listView.height
            border.color: "black"

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent

                text: modelData
            }

            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log("Delegate completed")
            }

            Component.onDestruction: {
                console.log("Delegate destruction")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to set the cacheBuffer to 0?

Comment: @eyllanesc Because my delegates is very complex. But cacheBuffer don't change described behaviour a lot after all.

Comment: if your delegate is complex, on the contrary it is necessary to have an adequate cacheBuffer, to establish it to zero implies that the components will be created at each moment consuming many resources.

Comment: @eyllanesc Before I began this research, all of delegates created at once and I waited 20-30 second opening of my screen.

Comment: mmm, having a creation of items in 20-30 seconds smells really bad, in that calculation that value has cacheBuffer ?, Are you not blaming an innocent ?, I think the problem is your delegate, not cacheBuffer, so For me you have an XY problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc 20-30 is for creation of all delegates, when height of delegate was linked to ListView height and delegate created at the screen creation (weird behaviour). I will optimise a delegate in future, but it's very informative by design and that's why contains a lot of objects. I can't refuse from some features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
 delegate: MyVeryComplexDelegate {
 }
```

by

```
delegate: Loader {
    width: expectedDelegateWidth
    height: expectedDelegateHeight // Otherwise you might create all...
    sourceComponent: MyVeryComplexDelegate {
    }
    active: someCriteriaYouFeelGoodAbout()
}
```

---

Now you will only have simple `Loader`s in your cache and you can decide which ones of those in the cache are active.

---

Probably better: Have parts of the `MyVeryComplexDelegate` loaded as the `ListView` wants, and just hide the most complex parts behind a `Loader` that turns active only if you really need the full complexity.

---

On your *strange findings* as far as I can explain them:

Regarding the difference between `root.height` and `listView.height`, the explanation is an issue that is subject to many questions:

While `root.height` references the property `height` of the window, which you have explicitly set, `listView.height` is determined by `anchors.fill: parent`, which results in setting the height to `root.contentItem.height` - and that is initially `0`. Therefore the delegates, initially all have a height of `0`, all of them would fit in the view and therefor have to be created, even if you load as lazy as possible. Later they will resize together with the `root.contentItem` and some will be destroyed again.

You can see that, when monitoring the height changes of your delegates and your `ListView`

The next thing is, that even if the delegate really fills the `ListView` from the beginning, a second delegate is instantiated. The reason for that is, the condition used by the `ListView`, when to create new delegates. For that the sum of heights - the displacement of the first has to be *larger* than the `ListView`. That is not fulfilled when it is *equal* to the height.

Increase the `height` of your delegate by a fraction of a pixel, and you are good.

```
height: root.height + 0.0001
```

Comment: Good workaround for the problem, but it's still reinventing the wheel. ListView should take on itself laziness

Comment: So I explained in an edit why some of your expected laziness does not work. And for the destruction, it seems it is sometimes just to lazy for you.